# mysql, is it possible to have multiple rows with group by?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get the rows based on testid and buildnumber.

the table i have looks like

```
+------+-----------+------------+
|testid|distanceAF3| buildnumber|
+------+-----------+------------+
|1     |13.1       | 1149       | 
|2     |12.1       | 1149       | 
|3     |9.3        | 1149       | 
|4     |15.2       | 1304       | 
|5     |19.4       | 1304       | 
|6     |23.3       | 1304       | 
+--+-----+-------+---------+----+
```

As you can see, if I group based on buildnumber, the groups are 1149 and 1304
I would like to get the rows based on buildnumber, but the as each build number has got different testid (testid 1,2 and 3 belong to 1149 and 4,5 and 6 belong to 1304 build), I would like to have all different testid as well.

the output would be

```
+------+-----------+------------+
|testid|distanceAF3| buildnumber|
+------+-----------+------------+
|1     |13.1       | 1149       | 
|2     |12.1       |            | 
|3     |9.3        |            | 
|4     |15.2       | 1304       | 
|5     |19.4       |            | 
|6     |23.3       |            | 
+--+-----+-------+---------+----+
```

Is it possible to do it with mysql??

Thanks

Comment: what is the output that you want? can you add it to the question?

Comment: I have really no idea how to do this. Could you please give me some guide? or help me??

Comment: Please edit your question and show your desired output.

Comment: you could use i.e. [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(test_id), buildnumber ...

Comment: You should do that in the programming language you're using to query mysql.

Comment: Yes, I agree, once I got query then i need to do programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select t.testid, t.distanceaf3, x.buildnumber
  from tbl t
  left join (select buildnumber, min(testid) as testid
               from tbl
              group by buildnumber) x
    on t.testid = x.testid
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d77e9/1/0

As an alternative -- I imagine you're using PHP? -- you can show or not show the BUILDNUMBER field depending on whether the current row's value is the same as the previous row (using the # you're at in the loop vs. the previous #)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a list of the `testid`s?  If so, `group_concat()` does this:

```
select buildnumber, group_concat(testid) as testid
from table t
group by buildnumber;
```